# Sorting Table Column

Tags: tables

Suppose I have a table with say two columns. How can I sort its rows based on the first column? Is it possible in latex? If I do it in another application (like MS Excel) can I import the data from my worksheet into a tabular?
I would be very happy if you suggest me a way to handle this sorting, the easier the better! BTW I looked at [sorting alphanumeric listing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6988/how-to-sort-an-alphanumeric-list) and didn't get it at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no doubt that `datatool` is the way to go here. However, it is possible to use the code from my answer to the sorting question to do this.

You need to define a new comparator that compares only the first column. This particular implementation wants something that has a top level expansion into a row. E.g., you can define a macro for each row.

```
\def\rowi  {C & foo & qwer \\}
\def\rowii {A & bar & asdf \\}
\def\rowiii{B & baz & zxcv \\}
```

The goal is to be able to write the following to get sorted rows.

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
Letters & Metasyntatic variables & Gibberish\\
\midrule
\sortfirstcol{\rowi\rowii\rowiii}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

In particular, the `\sortfirstcol{\rowi\rowii\rowiii}` should expand to the sorted rows. As with `\sortalpha`, `\sortfirstcol` is just a simple macro that expands `\sort` with the comparator `\sort@firstcol` as its first argument.

```
\newcommand*\sortfirstcol{\sort\sort@firstcol}
```

The comparator isn't extremely complicated, but it does need to extract the first column of each argument. For that, we use a helper macro. And in keeping with the spirit of the original answer, this version is expandable.

```
\def\sort@firstcol#1#2{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        \sort@fc@helper\expandafter#1#2#1#2%
}

\def\sort@fc@helper#1&#2\\#3&#4\\#5#6#7{%
    \ifnumcomp{\pdfstrcmp{#1}{#3}}<{0}
    {#7{#5}{#6}}% else
    {#7{#6}{#5}}%
}
```

The `\expandafter`s are going to expand the first two arguments a single time. For example, if the comparator is "called" as `\sort@firstcol{\rowi}{\rowii}{...}`, then it will expand to

```
\sort@fc@helper C & foo & qwer \\A & bar & asdf \\\rowi\rowii{...}
```

and so `#1` will be the tokens "C ", `#3` will be "A ", `#5` will be `\rowi`, `#6` will be `\rowii`, and lastly `#7` will be the `{...}` that is the continuation that gets passed to the comparator.

From here, it's identical to `\sort@alpha`: it compares `#1` and `#3`, passing `#5` and `#6` to the continuation.

Lastly, due to the representation of the rows, the `\sortend` and `\sortoutput` macros should be set to just expand to their argument:

```
\newcommand*\sortoutput[1]{#1}
\newcommand*\sortend[1]{#1}
```

The following is a complete example using the above code and the code from the previous answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\makeatletter
% #1 - comparator
% #2 - token list to sort
\newcommand\sort[2]{%
        \ifstrempty{#2}
        {}% else
        {%
                \sort@begin#1{}#2\sort@s\sort@begin
        }%
}

% helpers
\def\sort@s{\sort@s}
\def\ifsort@s#1{%
        \ifx\sort@s#1%
                \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else
                \expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi
}

% #1 - comparator
% #2 - tokens processed so far
% #3 - smallest token so far
% #4 - rest of the list
\def\sort@begin#1#2#3#4\sort@begin{%
        \ifsort@s{#4}
        {%
                \sortend{#3}%
                \sort#1{#2}%
        }% else
        {%
                \sort@go#1{#2}{#3}#4\sort@go
        }%
}

%     #1 - comparator
% #2 - tokens processed so far
% #3 - smallest token so far
% #4 - token under consideration
% #5 - rest of the list
\def\sort@go#1#2#3#4#5\sort@go{%
        #1{#3}{#4}{\sort@output#1{#2}{#5}}%
}
% #1 - comparator
% #2 - tokens processed so far
% #3 - rest of the list
% #4 - smaller of the two tokens
% #5 - larger of the two tokens
\def\sort@output#1#2#3#4#5{%
        \ifsort@s{#3}
        {%
                \sortoutput{#4}%
                \sort#1{#2{#5}}%
        }% else
        {%
                \sort@begin#1{#2{#5}}{#4}#3\sort@begin
        }%
}

\def\sort@numlt#1#2#3{%
        \ifnumcomp{#1}<{#2}
        {#3{#1}{#2}}% else
        {#3{#2}{#1}}%
}

\def\sort@numgt#1#2#3{%
        \ifnumcomp{#1}>{#2}
        {#3{#1}{#2}}% else
        {#3{#2}{#1}}%
}

\def\sort@alpha#1#2#3{%
        \ifnumcomp{\pdfstrcmp{#1}{#2}}<{0}
        {#3{#1}{#2}}% else
        {#3{#2}{#1}}%
}

\def\sort@firstcol#1#2{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        \sort@fc@helper\expandafter#1#2#1#2%
}

\def\sort@fc@helper#1&#2\\#3&#4\\#5#6#7{%
    \ifnumcomp{\pdfstrcmp{#1}{#3}}<{0}
    {#7{#5}{#6}}% else
    {#7{#6}{#5}}%
}

\newcommand*\sortnumlt{\sort\sort@numlt}
\newcommand*\sortnumgt{\sort\sort@numgt}
\newcommand*\sortalpha{\sort\sort@alpha}
\newcommand*\sortfirstcol{\sort\sort@firstcol}
\makeatother

% Change these to change out the sort outputs.
\newcommand*\sortoutput[1]{#1}
\newcommand*\sortend[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\def\rowi  {C & foo & qwer \\}
\def\rowii {A & bar & asdf \\}
\def\rowiii{B & baz & zxcv \\}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
Letters & Metasyntatic variables & Gibberish\\
\midrule
\sortfirstcol{\rowi\rowii\rowiii}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Finally, I should point out that this representation (that is, rows as macros) isn't necessary. Due to the way `\sort` processes its arguments, one could easily write a comparator that allowed one to write the following.

```
\sortfirstcol{%
    {C & foo & qwer}%
    {A & bar & asdf}%
    {B & baz & zxcv}%
}
\def\sortoutput#1{#1\\}
\def\sortend#1{#1\\}
```

Perhaps I should have done that. The comparator would be slightly simpler.

Also, as implemented, a space at the beginning or end of the first column matters. One could probably deal with that too.

Answer (score 4):

The [`datatool`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/datatool.html) package has quite a lot of functions to sort and analyse data.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of good techniques for transferring Excel or other spreadsheet data into latex source.  See this answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1801/tool-for-manipulating-latex-tables-html-to-latex/1803#1803).  If you are using a TeXShop on a Mac, there is also a built-in "Paste Spreadsheet Cells" macro that will do the trick.