# Good LaTeX Table Editor?

Tags: tables, editors, tools

For LaTeX tables editor, I am using [LaTable](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latable) version 0.7.1 which is good to a large extent. The only problem I have (so far) with this editor is the ability of adding multi-lines in a cell.

Can someone suggest a powerful table editor for LaTeX?

Comment: I'm not going to vote to close or anything, but you may want to look at this [parallel question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1801/tool-for-manipulating-latex-tables-html-to-latex) on tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: You might also want to look at some of the editors listed in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

Answer (score 8):

Have you seen [excel2latex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex) ?

There are a couple of other options [here](http://az.ctan.org/keyword/tables).

Comment: What is the meaning of az in `az.ctan.org`?

Comment: @Herbert: Maybe "Azerbaijan"?

Comment: It is both the first two letters in azTeX and the last two letters in ke1az, my ham call.

Answer (score 6):

You can also export tables to Latex in Gnumeric. It has several options of doing so (inline, or full page).

Comment: I'm a little disappointed with this feature. The full document export is much too complicated for me to cut and paste into another document, and the table fragement option appears to lose all formatting (at least, it loses multicolumn cells, and all alignment choices that I make.)

Answer (score 3):

A nice online service, though not very powerful, is that LaTeX table editor:

[Link](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latable)

Answer (score 2):

There's the [`latable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latable) package. It is described as a LaTeX table editor for Windows and Macintosh machines with the following features:

- real-time LaTeX code preview;
- limited clipboard support for import/export into other spreadsheet
  and text editors;
- CSV support;
- support for `tabular`, `array` and custom environments;
- custom column formats.