# graphical tools for tabular construction?

Tags: tables, minipage

I often use `R`'s `xtable` library or `emacs` `org-mode` to create tables in `LaTeX` (they are wonderful, by the way). I wonder if there are other tools people use which facilitate construction of large tables containing more text than data. I think I might have at one point also used OpenOffice/LibreOffice Calc's export tool designating delimiter (`&`) and eol (`\\`).

One remaining issue with most of these tools is that the generated tables by default do not wrap longer lines of text so I have to post-process with a tool like `Python` to insert the contents of each cell in a `minipage` environment. I wonder if anyone here has better workarounds for this type of application, particularly graphical tools which do not require the user to keep track of `&`s and `\\`s spanning multiple lines in a `.tex` file?

Comment: See some of the answers to this question: [Tool for manipulating LaTeX tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1801/2693).

Comment: Is pgfplotstable capable?

Comment: Why insert the contents of each cell into a minipage? Doesn't the `p{...}` column type work?

Comment: @Alan Munn, thanks -- that thread was very helpful. I have to try out Calc2LaTeX to see if multi-line fields are exported correctly.

Comment: @Karsus Ren, I was not aware of `pgfplotstable` and it looks great for formatting data tables, but I think it does not allow multi-line text (and so similar in functionality to R's `xtable` library, but with more control over formatting).

Comment: @You -- I have used `p{...}` before but it does not wrap text if I recall correctly. I'll have to check...

Comment: @crippledlambda Can we close this question as a duplicate then? (It won't be deleted, just won't allow further answers, and will point to the question I mentioned.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try pgfplotstable package, though it is not graphical.

As for the word wrapping, you should specify a column width at the start of the table environment.