# Methods to edit column order in an existing LaTeX table?

Tags: tables, editors

What is the best way of editing an existing LaTeX table? I need to swap the order of two columns and can't think of an efficient way of doing this.

My table is a long creature of the following structure:

```
A &     -0.523 &      26.94 &     0.8243 &     0.0000 &     -12.67 \\
B &     -0.614 &      30.02 &     0.8509 &     0.0000 &     -13.12 \\
C &     -0.630 &      32.92 &     0.9254 &     0.0000 &     -21.45 \
```

I need to change the values so that it is:

```
A &     26.94 &      -0.523 &     0.8243 &     0.0000 &     -12.67 \\
(etc)
```

The thoughts that I had were to import it into Excel and to drag columns around, and then use the `concatenate()` function to produce the `number & number` structure. I feel like there might be a better way of doing this that I am unaware of.

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions already on the site:  search for "table editor" to see a selection: e.g. [Tool for manipulating LaTeX tables (HTML to LaTeX)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1801/2693) and [Comprehensive list of tools that simplify the generation of LaTeX tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49414/2693)

Comment: @AlanMunn I don't see this ability in any of the tools mentioned. I'm familiar with some of them, but generally they seem to be useful for generating the table initially, not for editing an existing Latex table (though maybe I have not looked thoroughly enough).

Comment: I guess that's true.

Comment: I recommend renaming the question to be more specific to moving columns around, which would allow it to stand on its own and make it more useful for those googling.

Comment: Hi @MarkS.Everitt I just edited it - feel free to change it if you think it can be clearer. I'm amazed at all the great suggestions in response to this question.

Comment: That looks good. It certainly has gathered a lot of attention! I wish I'd seen it earlier and supplied the SED solution though. ;)

Comment: In Texmaker you can use Alt + Shift to select columns. Then just copy & paste.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Any editor with regular expression replace can easily swap columns. For example on the command line if `tab.tex` contains your input this regexp will swap column 2 and 3.
(You may need more or less backslashes in the regexp depending on the command line shell in use)

```
 sed -e "s/^\([^\&]*\)\&\([^\&]*\)\&\([^\&]*\)/\1\3\2/" tab.tex 
A       26.94      -0.523 &     0.8243 &     0.0000 &     -12.67 \\
B       30.02      -0.614 &     0.8509 &     0.0000 &     -13.12 \\
C       32.92      -0.630 &     0.9254 &     0.0000 &     -21.45 \
```

Comment: Thanks David - I'll try it out. That is a mind-melting regular expression.

Comment: the regexp is really just three ([^&])& groups that is, sequence of not-& followed by an &. It just needs the backslashes to hide the special characters from the shell (I was using bash shell, other command lines may be different)

Comment: I'm starting to understand it; thanks again. regexp is something I have tried to learn several times. It did work (though stripped out some of the `&`).

Comment: oh sorry you need \1&\3&\2& to put the &'s back in the replacement or possibly \&\&\3\&\2\& depending.

Comment: @David: lol, your last comment is a nice illustration of how your earlier "... regexp is really just ... " is very optimistic. I only use regexes only when I have to. If you don't use them every day, I think the syntax is very hard to remember and get right.

Comment: Although in this case it is not the syntax of regexp that is particularly hard but the syntax of (any unknown) command line. `&` isn't special in regexp so the regep to match that is `&` which is easy enough but `&` might be special to your command line and the syntax to pass `&` through to sed might be `\&` but it might not, depending on which command line processor you are using. You can avoid this of course by putting the regex in a file and then giving the file to set (with `-f` option but then it isn't a one-liner so less fun:-)

Answer (score 56):

As a tip for the future:

When creating big tables, I make a command to encode the row.

`\newcommand{\resultrow}[4]{#1 & #2 & #3 & #4 \\}`

If you then want to change the order/layout of something you only have to change the command definition.

You should take care in making the command as descriptive as possible, and that the arguments are in the order that they are logical to the command not to the table. This will make later changes to the order simpler.

*As per request, an example.* Take this table:

```
\begin{tabular}{l l l l}
  a & b & c & d \\
  2.33 & 4.55 & 5.66 & 7.88 \\
  3.44 & 5.66 & 6.77 & 9.00 \\
  .......
\end{tabular}
```

If you then want to change the order of the columns, well see the other answers to this question. I would however solve it like this:

```
\newcommand{\abcdresults}[4]{ #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 \\}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l}
  a & b & c & d \\
  \abcresults{2.33}{4.55}{5.66}{7.88}
  \abcresults{3.44}{5.66}{6.77}{9.00}
  .......
\end{tabular}
```

If you then want to change the order, you can just simply change the body of `\abcdresults` to for instance: `{\textbf{#3} & #1 & #2 & #4 \\}`

Comment: +1: for a simple, but nice approach to decouple presentation order from data order!

Comment: @DavyLandman Could you elaborate, please? I don't understand how to use your tip to solve the problem (though I'm using tabular quite frequently). Thanks!

Comment: @KeksDose Even if I may be late in the game, just to explain for future visitors. What Davy is doing is defining a command for writing a row, the abcdresults command. For this 4 column example the command takes four parameters and just outputs them in order putting an '&' in the middle and a new line at the end, just as you would normally do when writing a row.

Comment: +1. This method has a nice advantage: you can make the input of each row shorter by including some logic into the command. For example, if a column a limited set of possible options with a specific output for each one, you can program the command with `\ifthenelse` and have a single-character argument for in each row (`1` for one option, `2` for another, and so on). In fact, you can have more arguments than columns and utilise them in clever ways.

Answer (score 48):

+1 David for `sed` one-liner but with all due respect there is no better tool for working with tables than AWK. This is the solution for the above problem!

```
awk  'BEGIN {FS="&";OFS="&"}{print $1,$3,$2,$4,$5}' file.csv > newfile.csv
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I need one more tip to get this to work right, though. I understand that FS sets the separator, but how would I get awk to understand that the ``\\`` at the end of each line is not part of the last field, but the end of line?

Answer (score 21):

There are already good answers here, but there's a moral imperative to point out that, of course, there's an easy way to do this in emacs (or xemacs), without using regular expressions.  You can copy a column to a register using `copy-rectangle-to-register`, paste it in as a new column using `insert-register`, and then delete the unwanted column using `delete-rectangle`.  It's less fancy than using a regular expression, but easier to do one step at a time, making sure it's doing exactly what you want.

For the sake of completeness, use `C-Space` to mark one corner of the rectangle, and move to the opposite one. Then you can invoke the command you want on the rectangle defined by the two corners.

Comment: Definitely +1 for using "column edit mode" in your text editor. I think column edit mode would be faster than the awk/sed regex because it would take me at least 5 minutes to create from scratch the above regex... when column edit would be done in 2 minutes.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use Emac's Org mode to convert the data to a table with `(org-table-create-or-convert-from-region)` and move the columns around with `M-<left>` and `M-<right>`. Then you can either export it in LaTeX format or save it as a text file.

Comment: Yes I nearly gave an emacs rectangle answer rather than sed, so +1, although someone claimed in a comment to an answer I gave to a different question that not everyone uses emacs, and also the rectangle comamnds require the input is nicely lined up as in the MWE, whereas the sed or awk field based versions will match fields even if the input file is less well padded for alignment of the entries.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, in emacs, if the input is not as nicely aligned as in the MWE, `align` and `align-current` work well and can take care of that.

Comment: well yes it's to be expected that emacs would take care of you:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your regexp answer is clearly the zippier one, but what do you mean spreading strange rumors that not everyone uses emacs?

Comment: @PhilHirschhorn I also hear that there are some strange people who use something called "Microsoft Word" instead of LaTeX. The world never ceases to amaze.

Answer (score 21):

Some TeX editors, e.g. WinEdt and TeXnicCenter and also text editors, e.g. Notepad++, offer a *rectangular selection* feature which is highly useful for editing tables.

For the **WinEdt** users, this nice and often overlooked functionality is in the *Status Line*.

[image]

If you click on `LINE` it becomes `Block` and that switches to the rectangle mode. This allows the user to select rectangular regions and perform copy paste options as usual.

[image]

This is especially useful to fill in the missing `&` columns to tabular data imported from Excel, MATLAB etc. via copying one column of `&` and pasting it between columns.

**TeXnicCenter 2** makes rectangular selections if keys <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> are pressed while selecting. The same is true for **Notepad++**.

Comment: Also very useful to know! Apparently you can do this in TextWrangler using a "rectangular selection" function with the command `Option-drag` or `shift-option-click` (though I can't get it to work).

Comment: @dgs Thanks a bunch for the addition. I didn't know that TC2 have that option too.

Comment: You're welcome. Actually it was this very feature which made me dump TC1, even though TC2 still is an alpha release.

Answer (score 6):

In TeXShop (for Mac Users)
(1) Hold the `<option>` key down and then click and drag the mouse to select a column.
(2) Cut `<command><X>` and
(3) Paste `<command><V>`
to place it as a new column of your table where desired.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In Excel you don't need to use `concatenate` to keep the table structure. If you import the table as in your MWE, you should be able to keep the `&` separators and the `\\` line breaks in separate columns. Once you swap the columns, you can save it as a tab-delimited `.txt` file and you are done. The `&` and `\\` will be separated from the data by a tab, but that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: That's very useful to know. Do you choose a space as your delimiter when importing?

Comment: I use space and tab when importing; most importantly, I look for the visual cue in the Excel import-window that tells you how the data will be imported, and choose the delimiters accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Like emacs, Vim has a column selection mode (^V) which will allow you to select columns and move them about. So `^v {select column} d {move to new location} p`. And there's an extension called Tabular which will allow you to reformat tables with ease as well.

Answer (score 2):

In [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org/) menu, click on 'LaTex' then 'Manipulate Tables' and you can cut and paste columns.

You do not need to select the whole column, but rather simply place the cursor in one of the rows of the column you want to cut.

Comment: yes but the rectangular selection on TeXStudio, which is done with ctrl+alt+shift+leftmouse+drag, is uneasy.

Comment: @emeryville You can just place the cursor in the column, no need to select it whole. I added a clarification to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use one of Sam Franke’s excellent tools for manipulating delimited text files, `CSVed` and `uniCSVed`. Those are true  graphical interfaces. You find the programs [at this web-page](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Excel Macro](http://dataninja.wordpress.com/2006/01/20/excel-to-latex/) for exporting table content to a latex table. It is not perfect but when prototyping large tables and reordering columns this is quite helpful.

Comment: The official homepage of excel2latex would either be http://ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex or https://launchpad.net/excel2latex

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with ed in a shell script, for example :

```
#!/bin/sh
ed tab.tex <<END
1,$s/^\([^&]*\)&\([^&]*\)&\([^&]*\)&\([^&]*\)&\([^&]*\)&\([^&\]*\)/\1\&\3\&\2\&\4\&\5\&\6/
w
q
END
```