# \expandafter parameters that are not commands

Tags: macros, expansion

I'm using a custom command to format all tables in a document. Some tables share properties other than style, such as column definitions and headers, which is why [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56056/14697) inspired me to even more reduce repeated code.

Inserting header data into the table command did not cause any problems, while for inserting column definitions I had to find out how to expand the column definitions before insertion. `\expandafter` solved that problem.

Now, I'd like to combine parameters given as commands and others given as literals, e.g. the table's data. If the to-be-expanded command that contains the column definitions happens to be the first argument, this works fine. What do I need to do if conversely a literal is the first argument? How do I make `\expandafter` bypass a pair of curly braces instead of a command?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\colDef}{{cc}}  
    \newcommand{\tableBody}{a & b\\}

    \newcommand{\myTabA}[2]{%
        \begin{tabular}{#1}
            1 & 2\\\midrule
            #2
        \end{tabular}       
    }

    %same command with #1 and #2 switched
    \newcommand{\myTabB}[2]{%
        \begin{tabular}{#2}
            1 & 2\\\midrule
            #1
        \end{tabular}       
    }       

    %draw table A
    \expandafter\myTabA\colDef{\tableBody}
    \expandafter\myTabA\colDef{c & d\\} 

    %draw table B
    \expandafter\myTabB\expandafter\tableBody\colDef

    %produces error
    %\expandafter\myTabB\expandafter{c & d\\}\colDef    

\end{document}
```

Comment: The answers to this question will help you out I think: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22288/14100

Comment: True, that's it. Thanks, Scott and Hendrik. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I wish `etextools`'s documentation did not look like a geocities website! All that is missing is a `<blink>` tag.

Comment: @Aditya [Geocitied tex.stackexchange](http://wonder-tonic.com/geocitiesizer/content.php?theme=2&music=4&url=tex.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The etextools package provides some tools for doing this, for example

```
\ExpandNextTwo{code}{arg 1}{arg 2}
```

as used below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etextools}

\begin{document}

   \newcommand{\colDef}{{cc}}  
   \newcommand{\tableBody}{a & b\\}

   \newcommand{\myTabA}[2]{%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}
        1 & 2\\\midrule
        #2
    \end{tabular}       
}

%same command with #1 and #2 switched
\newcommand{\myTabB}[2]{%
    \begin{tabular}{#2}
        1 & 2\\\midrule
        #1
    \end{tabular}       
}       

%draw table A
\expandafter\myTabA\colDef{\tableBody}
\expandafter\myTabA\colDef{c & d\\} 

%draw table B
\expandafter\myTabB\expandafter\tableBody\colDef

% no longer produces error
\ExpandNextTwo{\myTabB}{c & d\\} \colDef

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

It's simpler of you push the expansion control into the macro, so it always expands the first token of `#2` once, then you don't need `\expandafter` in the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\colDef}{{cc}}  
    \newcommand{\tableBody}{a & b\\}

    \newcommand{\myTabA}[2]{%
        \begin{tabular}{#1}
            1 & 2\\\midrule
            #2
        \end{tabular}       
    }

    %same command with #1 and #2 switched
    \newcommand{\myTabB}[2]{%
        \def\temp{\begin{tabular}}%
           \expandafter\temp\expandafter{#2}
            1 & 2\\\midrule
            #1
        \end{tabular}       
    }       

    %draw table A
    \expandafter\myTabA\colDef{\tableBody}
    \expandafter\myTabA\colDef{c & d\\} 

    %draw table B
    \myTabB\tableBody\colDef

    %produces error (not now!)
    \myTabB{c & d\\}\colDef    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David, that's less redundant and a lot more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

I've ended up using an `etextools` command inside the tabular definition, thus drawing from both all answers.

```
\newcommand{\myTabB}[2]{%
    \expandnext{
    \begin{tabular}}{#2}
        1 & 2\\\midrule
        #1
    \end{tabular}       
}
```