# How to use variables inside a command when generating a table?

Tags: tables, macros

I'm not sure about the question, since I do not really understand why it fails.

[I tend to use commands to generate my tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55995/methods-to-edit-column-order-in-an-existing-latex-table/56056#56056), and when I use the `#1` style of accessing the arguments it works. But now I have a wider dataset, and need to use this trick: [How to define a command that takes more than 9 arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/how-to-make-define-a-command-that-takes-more-than-9-arguments) to get all the arguments together in one command.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\rowdata[2]{%
    \def\firstPoint{#1}%
    \def\secondPoint{#2}%
    \createRow
    % #1 & #2 \\ would work.
}
\newcommand\createRow{ %
    \wlog{\firstPoint \secondPoint} % it appears in the log 
    \firstPoint & \secondPoint \\ % this fails
}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
        \rowdata{a}{b}
        \rowdata{d}{b}
        \rowdata{a}{c}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And this gives the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\createRow ...dPoint } \firstPoint & \secondPoint 
                                                  \\ 
l.16        \rowdata{a}{b}
```

If I remove the `&` it does work, but then I cannot create a table anymore.

So what is happening here?

Comment: Alignment cells form groups, so the definition of `\secondPoint` is forgotten as soon as `&` is digested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In comments, the reason is pointed out: `&` besides other things ends and begins a group so the definition of `\secondPoint` is forgotten. Solution: use `\gdef` :

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\rowdata[2]{%
    \gdef\firstPoint{#1}%
    \gdef\secondPoint{#2}%
    \createRow
    % #1 & #2 \\ would work.
}
\newcommand\createRow{ %
    \wlog{\firstPoint \secondPoint} % it appears in the log 
    \firstPoint & \secondPoint \\ % this fails
}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
        \rowdata{a}{b}
        \rowdata{d}{b}
        \rowdata{a}{c}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `stringstrings` package has a `\getargs` command that works like Unix.  It will parse a single argument into `\argi`, `\argii`, etc.  The total number of arguments is in `\narg`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\begin{document}
\getargs{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 FinalArgument}
There are \narg~arguments.  The thirteenth is \argxiii
\end{document}
```

The result to this example is:

There are 13 arguments. The thirteenth is FinalArgument

======

In answer to a request for a MWE, I note that `stringstrings` did suffer the same problem the user noticed above, which is that the getargs results were not global.  However, I remedy that here with a `\makeatletter` redefinition of `\getargs`.

Then I redefined `\rowdata` to take one big space-separated argument.  So here is how one prints a 12 column table with a command that generates the rows.  Furthermore, the argument is merely space-separated data, not separate {} blocks.

AFTERTHOUGHT:  The \rowdata command can take more than just typed data as its content.  For example, you could have \today as part of the data, and it would take up three arguments (i.e., columns) of the table

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\getargs[2][q]{\+%
  \if v#1\def\@mode{q}\else\def\@mode{#1}\fi
  \edef\@argv{#2}%
  \@getstringlength{\@argv}{@stringsize}%
  \setcounter{@iargc}{0}%
  \whiledo{\value{@stringsize} > 0}{%
    \addtocounter{@iargc}{1}%
    \getaword[\@mode]{\@argv}{1}%
    \expandafter\global\expandafter\edef\csname arg\roman{@iargc}\endcsname{\thestring}%
    \removeword[e]{\@argv}%
    \edef\@argv{\thestring}%
    \@getstringlength{\@argv}{@stringsize}%
  }
  \edef\narg{\arabic{@iargc}}%
\?}
\makeatother
\newcommand\rowdata[1]{%
  \getargs{#1}
  \argi & \argii & \argiii & \argiv & \argv & \argvi & \argvii & 
  \argviii & \argix & \argx & \argxi & \argxii \\    }
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{l l l l l l l l l l l l}
        \rowdata{a b 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12}
        \rowdata{d b blah 3 45 89 s rt 343 \today}
        \rowdata{a c 45 dfgf 454 454 fd 7 sds ssd s s}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot see how this answers the question. Could you please embed it into the example provided in the question?

Comment: Remark: You can use `\expandafter\xdef` instead of `\expandafter\global\expandafter\edef` ;)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes And `\global\expandafter\edef` would suffice anyway, because `\global` wants to find a "def" command after it, so it starts expansion.

Comment: Thanks.  And note I edited the example to show how a command can be used as part of the \rowdata input.