# Tables in LaTeX

Tags: tables

What is the fastest/easiest way to create and edit tables on LaTeX on a Mac?

I need a fast way to merge cells, add and delete rows e.t.c. I have tried using lyx and some online table generators but they're rather complicated.

Thanks

Comment: You can use LibreOffice/OpenOffice.org to create your tables using the module *Calc* and then export them to LaTeX using the extension [`calc2latex`](http://calc2latex.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Comprehensive list of tools that simplify the generation of LaTeX tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49414).  Also: [Tool for manipulating LaTeX tables (HTML to LaTeX)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1801)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  If you need to delete rows, then using a transposed table as in [tabular input by columns (i.e. transpose a table)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75793/tabular-input-by-columns-i-e-transpose-a-table) would help.

Comment: Tell us, why you need a fast way to produce tables in LaTeX, which, of course isn't a spreadsheet software.

Comment: Most people use the same editor that they use for the rest of the document.

Comment: If you need to change a table a lot, I don't think LaTeX is the right tool. It is more something you use to typeset the table when its final content and form is decided. (Obviously, you might tweak it a bit but basically, if you need to make lots of changes to structure or content, you aren't really at the final typesetting stage.)

Comment: 'Easiest'/'fastest' both rather broad and potentially opinion-based. We'd also need some idea of what you want to achieve in more details.