# Difficulties making a table

Tags: tables

I'm working on a presentation and I would like to type a table. The problem is that I know how to do a table but not this kind of table.
I would like to do a table that really looks like [this one](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avions_de_chasse_de_cinqui%C3%A8me_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ration) at the headlin e " Comparatif technique " without pictures( it is not presented the same way in English )

When I try to do it, when I want to fill in the block it extends to the other columns and then my table goes out of my page from the right. I would like it goes to the line so each column are not too large so that the whole table appears. Sorry for my mistakes in english.

Comment: If you want to create tables online you can do it. There are several very simple tools to use. You can see this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1801/tool-for-manipulating-latex-tables-html-to-latex

Comment: If you are searching for examples, look for` tabular` rather than `table`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! (Nice pic of Benoit Mandelbrot, by the way!)

Comment: He is the best !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following? The code employs a `tabularx` environment and columns of (modified) type `X`, which allow automatic line-breaking.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
% The '\hspace{0pt}' part is a well-known trick to get around TeX's
% inability to hyphenate the very first word of a (logical) paragraph.

\begin{document}   
\begin{table}
% 1st column: type 'l'; next 7 columns: type 'L'
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|*{7}{L|}}
\hline
Avion de chasse & furtivité & supercroisière & 
super-manœu-vrabilité & vol à haute altitude & 
liaisons de données tactique & fusion des données & 
Génération selon les classements \\
\hline
 & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\oddsidemargin = 0.25cm
\begin{document}   
\begin{table}[h]
% 1st column: type 'l'; next 7 columns: type 'L'
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}\hline
&&&&&&&\\
Avion de chasse & furtivité & supercroisière & 
super-manœu-vrabilité & vol à haute altitude & 
liaisons de données tactique & fusion des données & 
Génération selon les classements \\
&&&&&&&\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I have removed all packages and adjusted the table. I hope that you like it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: With the column width you selected and the `geometry`settings your table will be wider than the textwidth. You might want to adjust the settings to circumvent that.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\oddsidemargin = 0.25cm
\begin{document}   
\begin{table}[h]
% 1st column: type 'l'; next 7 columns: type 'L'
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.25cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.25cm}|p{1.25cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{2cm}|}\hline
&&&&&&&\\
Avion de chasse & furtivité & supercroisière & 
super-manœu-vrabilité & vol à haute altitude & 
liaisons de données tactique & fusion des données & 
Génération selon les classements \\
&&&&&&&\\
\hline
 & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I have changed the column sizes. It is reduced by 2 cm. I hope it fits the page size you have selected.

Comment: Your table is wider than text width. Added empty rows before and after column headers doesn't make them nicer, column headers are poorly formatted ... (my opinion). Comments before table doesn't has any relation to your table design, etc